# MVC File Upload return Parial View issue

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

If my Razor is coded with `@Html.BeginForm (enctype = "multipart/form-data")` for my file upload, it will always return me a new page instead of to my DIV tag column. `@Ajax.BeginForm` offers DIV tag control, but in some circumstances, I have to use the hack with the `Javascript` and IE doesn't support on it.

Is there a way for me avoid page redirection by using `@Html.BeginForm` because I want to maintain my web design as much as SPA. Thanks.

Comment: if you are trying to upload a file with ajax just by posting the form then it will postback your whole page and you will see full page postback.  There are certain ways to post a file using ajax. 1.) Use some jQuery fileupload plugin 2.) send base 64 data to server if your are uploading image.

Comment: You cannot use `@Ajax.BeginForm()` to upload files, but you can use `FormData` - refer [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29293637/how-to-append-whole-set-of-model-to-formdata-and-obtain-it-in-mvc/29293681#29293681)